# Disable HTML Select Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this list

```html
<select name="method" required class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Cash</option>
    <option value="2">Credit</option>
</select>

<select name="method2" class="form-control">
<?php
while (...) {
echo '<option value="id">Title</option>';
}

?>
</select>
```

If the user chooses the Cash option from the first "select method",

the second "select method2" must be disabled,
and if he chooses Credit, it must be activated

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck exactly? 1) handle the "change" event of the first dropdown, 2) get the value currently selected there, 3) write an `if` statement to decide whether to enable or disable the dropdown. 4) set the disabled property correctly on the dropdown as per your logic. I don't see any reason why you couldn't have made some attempt to research and implement each of those steps yourself? We're happy to help at stackoverflow if you have a genuine problem, but it really isn't a do-my-thinking service. Nothing you've asked for is new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In it's simplest form, you can add an event listener to your first select box that listens for a **change** event:

```js
let selectOne = document.querySelector("#select-1"), selectTwo = document.querySelector("#select-2");

selectOne.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (selectOne.value == 1) {
    selectTwo.disabled = true;
  } else {
    selectTwo.disabled = false;
  }
})
```

```html
<select name="method" required class="form-control" id="select-1">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="1">Cash</option>
    <option value="2">Credit</option>
</select>

<select name="method2" class="form-control" id="select-2">
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="1">Just For Demo Purposes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just tell me why did you just make variable for selects and then used it inside of event listener? It doesn't have sence...

Comment: Well, respect :) sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First you can listen for any changes in the select using `change` event

The `select` element in HTML has a `disabled` property, which is set to false by default unless its explicitly disabled, you can set this property to True or False to enable or disable the select respectively

```js
const sel = document.getElementById('selectm');
const sel2 = document.getElementById('selectm2');

handler = () => {
    console.log(sel.value)
    if (sel.value == 1) sel2.disabled = true
    else sel2.disabled = false;
}
sel.addEventListener('change', handler)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="method" required class="form-control" id="selectm">
        <option value="0">Default</option>
        <option value="1">Cash</option>
        <option value="2">Credit</option>
    </select>
    
    <select name="method2" class="form-control" id="selectm2">
        <option value="1">test</option>
        <option value="2">test-1</option>

    </select>
</body>
</html>
```